# What are the limitations of performing a Firestore query over a large collection

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to use Firebase Firestore for my next project but I need some help understanding the limitations of what is possible with Firestore queries.

Basically, I would like to perform queries over collections with large amounts of documents but upon doing research I have come across conflicting information.

This video (from the Firebase team): https://youtu.be/W3xIOQu0h1w?t=11m50s states that you can perform a query over a collection with "[billions](https://youtu.be/W3xIOQu0h1w?t=13m1s)" of documents and maintain the same level of performance compared to a query over a collection with a few documents.

Then, I came across this [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/413) where the poster states that queries are taking too long and demand alot from the system. A member of the Firebase team answers by stating that performing a query over a collection containing 35k documents is beyond the "performance envelope".

So can someone point me in the right direction concerning Firestore queries and its limitations.

Please let me know if I was not clear in any part of this post.

Answer (score 3):

That GitHub issue you linked to is specifically talking about *offline* searches.  This means the Firestore backend service is not available, so the search is performed on the client.  This is a very different situation than when the client is online and the service can perform the query in a massively scalable way. (Client apps are never massively scalable.)